# AJAX Get with Web API 2 routing

Tags: c#, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to teach myself how to use web api attribute routing. It works fine when I use a post, but I cannot get a "get" method working with parameters

Here is the post that works:

knockout

```
self.ajaxTest = function () {
$.ajax("tasks", {
  data: ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }),
  type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (result) { alert(result) }
});
};
```

API Controller

```
[Route("documents/tasks")]
public string SubmitDocuments()
{
  return "test";
}
```

And below is the get that fails. I've tried a few different approaches. The get url seems to mess up my routing everytime.

```
  self.ajaxTest = function () {
$.ajax("documents/checkForDocuments", {
  data: { test: "abc" },
  type: "get", contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (result) { alert(result) }
});
};
```

API Controller

```
[Route("documents/checkForDocuments")]
public string CheckForDocuments(string test)
{
  return "test";
}
```

Any suggestions? Am I just doing this all wrong? No matter what I do, I can't seem to land a breakpoint in c# with the get method

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `Route` attribute with a `GET`:

```
[GET("documents/checkForDocuments/{test}")]
```